# ¿Cómo usar correctamente un IF dentro de un stored procedure en MySql?

Tags: mysql, condiciones, stored-procedure

Estoy usando un `IF` dentro de un *stored procedure*:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_Registro_Crear (IN paramero1 VARCHAR(50), IN Parametro2 INT)
BEGIN
    IF (1 = 0) THEN

    END IF;
END;
```

Pero obtengo el siguiente error:

```
consulta SQL:


CREATE PROCEDURE SP_Registro_Crear (IN paramero1 VARCHAR(50), IN Parametro2 INT)
BEGIN
    IF (1 = 0) THEN

    END IF
MySQL ha dicho: Documentación

#1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'END IF' en la linea 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mas allá de que estás creando un procedimiento almacenado, te invito a leer la doc. oficial de MySQL respecto a *`IF STATMENT`*<sup>1</sup>

Que espera una sintaxis de esta forma (*ejemplo extraido de la doc. referenciada*):

```
IF search_condition THEN statement_list
    [ELSEIF search_condition THEN statement_list] ...
    [ELSE statement_list]
END IF
```

Entonces si analizas el código que presentas tu código carece del segmento llamado: **statment_list**, para indicar que acciones se llevarían acabo si la condición establecida se cumple.

**Ejemplo**

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE mostrarValor(IN Id INT)
    BEGIN
        IF Id > 10 THEN
            SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE id = Id;
        END IF;
    END
//
```

Como notas en este ejemplo, estoy creando un procedimiento almacenado que una vez que recibe un valor numérico, evalúa si este es mayor a 10 y si es cierto entonces obtiene todos los registros de una tabla X cuyo id sea igual al valor recibido como argumento.

Entonces durante la declaración de tu PA no deberías estar omitiendo escribir la lógica que se ejecutará si es que la condicional se cumple.

**Referencias**

- <sup>1</sup> [Statment `IF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html)

Comment: a okey, perfecto, lo probe sin la estruccion "DELIMITER //" y no funciono, tenia que agregarle eso. Muchas Gracias!